# What is the advantage to initializing activerecord objects with a block instead of a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Reading through the [docs for creating an activerecord object](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#create), I saw that you can do the following:

You can initialize an object with a hash, like so,

```
user = User.create(name: "David", occupation: "Code Artist")
```

Or you can initialize an object with a block

```
user = User.new do |u|
  u.name = "David"
  u.occupation = "Code Artist"
end
```

Can someone tell me why you would want to be able to do it with a block? Is there a specific computer-science or developer best practices reason where block initialization would be an advantage?

Comment: I wouldn't say there was a best practice in this case, other than to consider readability mostly. Ruby often offers several ways of doing a particular thing, sometimes with advantages depending upon context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most important difference is that you can't assign [protected attributes](https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes#usage) with a hash - because the hash is assumed to come from an insecure source, such as a submitted form.

With the block syntax you can assign any attributes and do anything else to the object. It may not seem useful with `new`, but it's pretty useful with `create` or `find_or_create`:

```
# won't work (at least shouldn't - in a properly secured app)
User.find_or_create_by_email!("admin@mysite.com", {is_admin: true})


# will work
User.find_or_create_by_email!("admin@mysite.com") do |u|
  u.is_admin = true
end
```

Comment: That's good to know!  Yes, I can see how it would be a terrible idea to allow random form data to set permissions that ought to be highly restricted.